# Why do timestamp column returns empty value in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have some json files in s3 of which I am trying to analyze in redshift and redshift spectrum.
s3 file has a key that has a timestamp value in the format `"Thu, 18 Mar 2021 08:50:35 +0000"`and when I am trying to query this particular column in redshift it returns an empty value,
**note other keys in the s3 file is being fetched by redshift only the published date key having timestamp data type is returned as empty.**

```
SELECT b.published_date
FROM  jatinspectrum.extable a, a.enteries b
```

**this query is executed successfully but no output**

Comment: If this query returns no rows, one of the tables is empty.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i am reading data from json files stored in s3, which has various keys, one of its key is published date which i can see in s3 bucket, also other keys forexample title i am able to see through redshift but only published date which has data type timestamp is returned empty.

Comment: @GordonLinoff s3 file is perfect all the keys with their values are there

Comment: Questions: When you say "empty" do you mean NULL value or zero rows or something else?  Why are you cross joining with table "enteries" from schema "a" (if that is what you are doing)? What is the file format of the objects in S3 for external table "extable"?  Can you post the external table ddl for this table (especially how is the date-time format set up)?  The likely answer is that Redshift cannot read the data for this column correctly due to setup issues but that is only a guess.

Comment: @BillWeiner empty means null value.I am followqing this to query my nested data in s3 files https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-query-nested-data-sqlextensions.html. file format of s3 object is json. how do i find the ddl?
i was reading this is this a solution to my problemhttps://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/query-table-athena-timestamp-empty/

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  This still leaves us with timestamp format issues.  A quick look at the docs shows "Timestamp values in text files must be in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS, as the following timestamp value shows: 2017-05-01 11:30:59.000000 ."  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html I suspect this is the issue.

Comment: Even I thought so, https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/query-table-athena-timestamp-empty upon closure look to this document says that i need to define the column datatype as `string` but right now it is defined as `timestamp` because like you @BillWeiner said the format redshift expects is different  from the format in the json file